# What do the words 「出ないのって」 and 「だる」mean?

Tags: words, particles

They are bold in the following sentence:

まあまあ 出【で】るの**出【で】ないのって**ビヤ**だる** 一ぱいほどの玉【たま】を出【だ】しちまってな。

Comment: Maybe it would help if you asked what the phrase 出るの出ないの and the compound ビヤだる are.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 「Verb or adjective + の + **Same** verb or adjective in **negative** form + の + って」

makes an idiomatic expression meaning:

> "Is it ever ~~?" or "Does it ever ~~?"

In other words, this structure emphasizes the meaning of the verb or adjective.

I would be inclined to believe that the sentence is about pachinko.  ***You would need to use more words to write your quetions than you have been using, explaining the context and showing us what you yourself have found out so far***.  People here are too nice to say something like that so I just did because it is the truth.

Trust me, you will get better answers and do so more quickly.

If it were actually about pachinko, 「出るの出ないのって」 would mean "Did it ever let out balls?", which in turn means "Did I ever win?"

「ビアだる」＝「ビア樽」＝ "beer barrel"

The speaker won enough balls to fill a beer barrel; It is figurative speech.  Once again, if the context were about playing pachinko.

Comment: Yes, it is about pachinko. Thank you for your suggestion. Next time, I'll put more detail when asking.